# Getting the PID of just started screen session

Tags: linux, bash, session, pid, gnu-screen

how do you get the PID of a just created screen session
like:

```
screen -dm -S test ping localhost

screen -ls
There is a screen on:

3310.test       (09/04/15 14:07:41)     (Detached)
```

I want 3310

I was looking at [Bash: Getting PID of daemonized screen session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320782/bash-getting-pid-of-daemonized-screen-session) but it didn't suit what I needed.

what I have been trying

```
screen -dm -s test ping localhost | echo $!
```

but the pid was off by two or one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that:

```
screen -dm -S test ping localhost & echo $!
```

It starts the screen process in the background (screen with `-d` starts anyway in "detachted mode") and prints its PID.

Comment: `user@ubuntu:~$ screen -dm -S test ping localhost & echo $!
[1] 3416
3416
user@ubuntu:~$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
        3417.test       (09/04/15 14:22:53)     (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-user.

[1]+  Done                    screen -dm -S test ping localhost`
which seems to be precisely giving pid's off by 1.

Comment: Hm, screen calls clone() and creates a childprocess whose pid i the next available (so not always +1). It is a bit circumstantial, but you can do the following: `strace screen -dm -S test ping localhost 2>&1 | awk '$0~/^clone/{print $NF}'` It does a strace of the parent process of screen, searches for the clone syscall and exracts the pid.

Comment: thanks. I ended up just setting a predefined unique name and grep'ing the name in screen -ls and matching to get the pid.